# How can I run 'dotnet test' on a solution file with both UWP and .NET Core / .NET 6 test projects?

Tags: msbuild, vstest, vstest.console.exe, dotnet-test, vstest.console

I have a solution that contains several .NET Standard, .NET Core, .NET 6, and finally **UWP** projects in it.

Additionally, I have test projects for everything, including the UWP projects.

My problem is, is that I cannot run the `dotnet test`, or even the `dotnet build`, command on my solution and have it actually work.  I get the following exception each time I attempt to use a `dotnet` command on the solution:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v17.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v17.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

It appears to happen any time that I have a UWP project in my solution.

This is frustrating, because I would like to have one (think build system) way to restore, build, and test my solution with multiple project types.

In order to do anything with my whole solution, I need to resort to using MSBuild commands for build operations, such as `msbuild /t:restore`, or `vstest.console` commands when targeting my UWP tests.  When not targeting UWP projects, I can use `dotnet` commands like normal.

Are the `dotnet` command line operations just not suitable for building and testing mixed solutions like mine?  Or is there something that I am missing?